# Which one is better (more select or more records) for performance in mysql?

Tags: mysql, query-performance

which below item is better in terms of performance in mysql:

- select from more records in one table
- more select from fever records in one table

(range of records >= 50000)

Comment: It all depends on factors like index. What is your input and expected output ?

Comment: What does 'more select' mean? Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is overhead in performing a query -- sending the query to the server, parsing the query, Optimizing, gathering, sending back, etc.  So, it is almost always better (faster) to do more work with fewer queries.

Please provide some concrete examples if you wish to discuss further.